# How do I make sure my view is oriented properly after full screen video?

Tags: ios, ios5, orientation

I've got a universal ipad/iphone app that allows the user to watch a video, which they can then expand into full screen mode.

I have implemented `(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`, and in that method I perform various setFrame calls on my view elements depending on whether they are in landscape or portrait orientation.

That all seems to work fine in normal use, i.e. rotating back and forth works fine.

But if the user starts in portrait mode, starts a video, goes to full screen mode, turns into landscape orientation, and then the video stops -- the elements are often not resized properly. They appear to be sized still as if they are portrait mode.

If I then turn to portrait mode, and then turn back to landscape, the view resets correctly.

The strange part is, I have implemented `(void)exitedFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification` and in there I print out the orientation, and it's seen correctly. I also call my code to reset the view elements based on the current orientation, and I am still having this problem.

Another related issue is sometimes when dealing with rotation, my views will end up too far up the screen, actually going under the status bar at the top of the device.

**Edit** Here's the latest example. I rotate to landscape mode during full screen video playback, and then when I left full screen video, you can see the issue with the navigation bar at the top of the view.

[image: Navigation bar goes underneath status bar after rotation during full screen video.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ViewController might not be rotating because another controller is the first responder. What you can do to avoid this is register the view controller to the device rotation changes and implement the rotation in the  selector you call when you receive such a notification.

In appDelegate:

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

In your view controller

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:)name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

In did rotate you can check the orientation with

```
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

Comment: This has helped with issues of rotation while my video is playing inline, but I am still experience issues when the video is full screen, rotated, and comes out of full screen. See my latest edit with the attached screenshot for an example of the issue.

Comment: I am going to award you the answer/bounty because it seems like since I've made your changes, the orientation issues have definitely improved. I think my only remaining issue has to do with the navigation bar being underneath the status bar after I exit full screen, which may be a different issue entirely.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to solve this is by presenting your view controller modally instead of using the navigation view controller.

Refer to Kenny's answer at [Problem pushViewController from Landscape to Portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822372/problem-pushviewcontroller-from-landscape-to-portrait)

Answer (score 1):

The navigation bar at the top of the view. I solved it, using this code ->

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated:YES];
```

Using this after your rotation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using this code after my rotation, after the section of code where I am positioning my elements on the view for the new orientation, and it didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Mason, did you logged and checked whether your method willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration: gets called after each state transition?

Comment: Yep it does get called. As you can see in my question, things are mostly working, in terms of rotation. It mostly seems to have problems when the rotation happens during the movie playback. Sometimes even when not in full screen.

Comment: So you say your method gets called even just before the problem appears but because of the method retrieves improper orientation value "...the various setFrame calls on your views" are fooled by wrong input?

Comment: I've got some debugging in place to log the orientation being reported, and that never seems to be the problem. The orientation is always reported properly when I get notified of a rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Your orientation may not get updated properly if there is another controller acting as a first responder. The best way to overcome this is to call the functions you use to orientate the screen at the method `viewWillAppear:` using the current orientation of the view controller: `[self interfaceOrientation]`

If you use a subclassed subview you may need to reimplement the methot layoutSubviews and call setNeedsLayout. Another thing that may be causing this is resigning the viewcontroller where you have the video as first responder (you mays search if somewhere you use the methon resignfirstresponder and try how it works without it). If this does not work, I don't know, this things may be very tricky and dependent on how you have implemented it. But for the things you say you do you should not need much code, since automatic rotation and resizing of views is handled now by the sizes inspector of the views editor.

I think that this should do.

Comment: I do already call the code to adjust my elements (same code that gets called during orientation changes) after I exit full screen. So I don't think that's it, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: I edited the response with more tips, if this does not work, I don't know. But as I said in the end, automatic resizing is handled by the views editor and you should not need much code for resizing a video view, just configuring appropriately the view in the sizes inspector should do.

Answer (score 0):

To me this latest screenshot does not look like an orientation change issue.
The navigation bar is basically off by the status bar's height.

Possibly your position calculation fails because you are using the view's frame 
while the fullscreen video (w/o status bar) is playing and this fails as soon as
the statusbar is back?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tested your theory about the timing issue with some breakpoints. The code to adjust the position calculations is definitely happening AFTER it has fullscreen video mode.