# Orientation change in navigationcontroller

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I added three view controllers into navigation controller. The first and second view   controller should support both orientation but third view controller only support for landscape mode. But when I navigate to the third view controller from second view controller in portrait mode, it is displayed in portrait mode. How can I rectify this one? I need third view controller to support only landscape orientation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an iOS 6 answer.

To make the UINavigationController honor the rotation preferences of its children, subclass it and override the following:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```

This works when creating a new UINavigationController and when popping back to earlier view controllers.  More info here - [ViewController in UINavigationController orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402401/viewcontroller-in-uinavigationcontroller-orientation-change)

To make it work when pushing new view controllers, add this to your subclass:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];

    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

The transition is a bit unpleasant, but it gets the job done.  More info here - [Problem pushViewController from Landscape to Portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822372/problem-pushviewcontroller-from-landscape-to-portrait)