# ViewController in UINavigationController orientation change

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

So I have the following hierarchy:

`UINavigationController` --> RootViewController (`UIViewController`) --> `UITableViewController` --> DetailViewController (`UIViewController`)

I want to lock the orientation on RootViewController to Portrait only, but leave all orientations for the rest view controllers.

If I put this to subclassed `UINavigationController`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

All view controllers are then locked to portrait.

My question is, is there a way to lock only RootViewController to Portrait, but leave all options for other view controllers?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

check the link here for fixing autorotation in iOS 6 and set orientation support per view basis: http://www.disalvotech.com/blog/app-development/iphone/ios-6-rotation-solution/

Here is what you could do:

1. Create a custom navigation controller that is a subclass of `UINavigationController`, in your .m file:

   ```
    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
         return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
    }
    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
         return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
    }
   ```
2. In your `AppDelegate.h`,

   ```
     @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

         UINavigationController *navigationController;
         ViewController *viewController;
     }

     @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
     @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
   ```

   and in `AppDelegate.m`,

   ```
     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
     {
           // set initial view
          self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

          viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];

          navigationController = [[CustomNavigationController alloc]
                       initWithRootViewController:viewController]; // iOS 6 autorotation fix
          [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];

           self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]
              initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

           [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController]; // iOS 6 autorotation fix
           //[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];

           [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


            return YES;
     }


     - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window  // iOS 6 autorotation fix
     {
             return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;

     }
   ```
3. in your rootViewController, for whatever the event push the second view controller, do this:

   ```
     - (IBAction)pushSecondViewController:(id)sender {

       // push second view controller
       SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
      }
   ```
4. in your each view controller, add

   ```
      - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{}
      - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{}
   ```

   for iOS 6, you can set each view controller whatever the orientation support you want individually.

   for iOS 5 and below, you can set

   ```
      - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{}
   ```

All the credits goes to John DiSalvo who wrote the sample app in the link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is almost a complete solution with one issue on iOS 7 & iOS 6.  If a view controller support portrait only, and the device is landscape before it pushes the view controller.  It's going to push the view controller in landscape!  This only affects the initial push.  After you rotate, it will honor the view controller's setting.  Any idea how to workaround it?

Comment: I am struggling to get this to work in storyboard format. Specifically, the appdelegate code. Does anyone have this done in iOS 7.1, using storyboards?

Comment: Can you take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45264386/child-view-controllers-orientation-change-in-uinavigationcontroller

Answer (score 2):

in singleton

```
-(void)setOrientationSupport:(BOOL)flag{

    flag_orientationSupport_ = flag;
}

-(BOOL)getOrientationSupport{

    return flag_orientationSupport_;
}
```

in appdelegate

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{

    if ([singleton getOrientationSupport])
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

add the following code in viewwillappear

for the viewcontroller you want support orientation

```
[singleton setOrientationSupport:YES];
```

to those controller you want disable orientation

```
[singleton setOrientationSupport:NO];
```

Comment: I left the app left orientation support to one orientation I need, and added the code. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your Nav controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Now, add this to your root view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

That should do it!

Answer (score 0):

To delegate the responsibility of defining allowed orientations to subviews of a UINavigationController, one can use the visibleViewController property of the nav controller to make the navigation controller "ask" it's child views for their supported orientations. The following code should work (Swift) :

1. Sub-classed navigation controller:

   ```
   override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

       if let visibleView = self.visibleViewController {
           return visibleView.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
       } else {
           return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
       }
   }
   ```
2. Sub-view (root view) of nav controller:

   ```
   // Restrict to portrait
   override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

I have been searching for the solution for hours!

So after implementing the needed methods everywhere. `shouldAutorotate` doesn't need to be set to `YES` because it is already set as default:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation{
     return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

When it is time to show the `UIViewController` which needs the orientation different than the other views, I created a `UIStoryboardSegue` with this implementation inside:

```
#import "Showing.h"

@implementation Showing

- (void)perform{
    NSLog(@"Showing");
    UIViewController *sourceVC = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *presentingVC = self.destinationViewController;

    [sourceVC.navigationController presentViewController:presentingVC 
                                                animated:YES 
                                              completion:nil];
}

@end
```

Inside the `UIStoryboard` I connected the views with this segue (**showing**):

[image]

It is just important, you are using

```
presentViewController:animated:completion:
```

**AND NOT**

```
pushViewController:animated:
```

otherwise the orientation won't be determined again.

---

I had been trying things like

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

**OR** this one inside the `UIViewController` where the orientation should change, and I also tryied to call it inside my custom `UIStoryboardSegues` before `presentingViewController` and `dismissViewController`:

```
[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];
```

**OR**

```
NSNumber *numPortrait = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:numPortrait forKey:@"orientation"];
```

But no one of them worked. Of course the last example shouldn't be an option, because if apple will change anything of their api this could cause problems inside your app.

I also tried to use the `AppDelegate` method and always determine the orientation inside this method after looking for the correct `UIInterfaceOrientation` of the actual `visibleViewController` but then it sometimes happened to crash when switching from one to another orientation. So I'm still wondering why its made so complicated and there seems also not to be any documentation where it is explained correctly.
Even following [this part didn't help](http://bit.ly/supportMultiInterfaceOrientation) me.