# Use current orientation on push view controller

Tags: ios, ios7, autorotate

I have two view controllers, `foo` that is portrait only and `bar` that is portrait + landscape.
When I push `bar` onto `foo`, `foo` always starts in portrait orientation. The user needs to tilt the phone after the push to get the os to detect the new orientation. What I would prefer is `foo` to be in landscape from the moment it is loaded, if the phone is landscape the moment it is pushed.

How could this be achieved on iOS6 and 7 both?

Answer (score 0):

I would add this code

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Adapt the orientation with your need
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait &&
            interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))
       return YES;
    else
       return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402401/viewcontroller-in-uinavigationcontroller-orientation-change

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633213/force-portrait-orientation-while-pushing-from-landscape-view-controller - try this too

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to support both landscape and portrait, but you want also the view to appear landscape if the phone is in landscape mode ? If so, have you try to put some condition ? I edit my answer

Comment: I see that this question is still open, did you find a solution ?