# IOS Allow portrait orientation only on some views and landscape on others

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, orientation, screen-orientation

Been trying to figure this one out, some answer in SO looked promising by didn't work. So hope someone can help.

I have an app running on IOS 7 (backwards compatible to IOS 5). Most of the views should be Portrait only, with a handful allowing landscape mode.

But... now matter what I do, I cannot get IOS to prevent views from going into Landscape mode.

The main view is a of type UIViewController. And implements all the methods below (yes tried everything :)

```
#pragma mark Orientation Methods

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}



- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)w {

    return (NSUInteger)[application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:w] | (1<<UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}

- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation:(UIWindow *)w {

    return (NSUInteger)[application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:w] | (1<<UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

But it still allows the user to change the view into landscape mode. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you using it inside a UINavigationController?  If so, your navigation controller is the one being asked about orientation preferences.  Try putting NSLog statements in these methods to verify that they're even being called.

Comment: That was it thanks Neal. Created a custom UINavigationController, and all is good. More info on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402401/viewcontroller-in-uinavigationcontroller-orientation-change