# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation not working

Tags: iphone, orientation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem pushViewController from Landscape to Portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822372/problem-pushviewcontroller-from-landscape-to-portrait)

In my app some of the view controller supports both landscape and portrait, while some supports only portrait.

I have 3 view controllers **FirstVC**, **SecondVC** and **ThirdVC**. I want :

- **FirstVC** and **ThirdVC** supports both landscape and Portrait
- **SecondVC** should support only portrait.

For that I :

- override `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` in all View Controller
- return `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);` in **SecondVC**
- returned YES in other two.

When I push **SecondVC** from **FirstVC** (in landscape mode), my SecondView is not shifting to portrait, it remains in landscape. But when I rotate SecondVC to portrait, it view rotate accordingly and again when I rotate, this time it remain in portrait does not change to landscape.

I hope I am clear.

Please can anyone know where I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What ios version? And what is your root vc? Tabbarcontroller?

Comment: I am using iOS 5.1 and my root is navigation controller.

Comment: have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822372/problem-pushviewcontroller-from-landscape-to-portrait

Comment: @LombaX, thanks man...It worked.Can you please provide it in answer so that I can mark it as accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look a this post [Problem pushViewController from Landscape to Portrait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822372/problem-pushviewcontroller-from-landscape-to-portrait)

You have to present the VC Modally.

Comment: I have one more query.Is it possible that, in one view controller one view supports orientation while some do not.I mean suppose I have one MainViewController which contains two UIView say FirstView and SecondView.At a time only one view will be visible.Suppose First view supports both orientation while second view only supports portrait.When I launch second view when device orientation is landscape, it should launch in portrait not in landscape mode.But my problem is it is launching in landscape.

Comment: AFAIK The shouldAutorotate method is called only when the device is rotating or when your viewcontroller is presented. If, from the same ViewController, you change the visible view, that method is not called. I suggest you to manage the two views from two different viewcontrollers